# Who is the man being executed in episode 1?

Tags: danganronpa

In the first scene of the first episode of Danganronpa The Animation, we see a man executed by being sent to the moon.

Who is he and why was he executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Jin Kirigiri](http://danganronpa.wikia.com/wiki/Jin_Kirigiri).

There are more details about this execution available on the Danganronpa [Wikia: Blast Off!](http://danganronpa.wikia.com/wiki/Blast_Off!).

> Jin was the headmaster of Hope's Peak Academy before Monokuma. He is also the father of Kyouko Kirigiri.